Numner of Graph functions
Let, T(V, E) be an undirected tree with n vertices, where V={$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$}. Let d(i)represent the degree of verticex $v_i$. Let f be a function from V to {1,2,...,n}. Compute the number of such functions f that satisfy the following condition for each $i \in $ {1,2,...,n}:
$$f(v_i) \geq\frac{\sum\limits_{(v_i, v_j) \in E}f(v_j) } {d(i)} $$
This means f should be such that the value it assigns to each vertex is no less than the average of the values it assigns to its neighbours.
My approach : For two vertices, $v_1 and v_2$ it is simply $f(v_1)\geq f(v_2)$ and $f(v_2)\geq f(v_1)$ then both the vertices have same color then 2 function exists.
Foe theree vertices also
$f(v_1) \geq f(v_2)$, $f(v_3)\geq f(v_2)$ and  $f(v_2)\geq\frac{f(v_1)+f(v_3)}{2}$ then after simple calculations $f(v_1)=f(v_2)=f(v_3)$. Thus only 3 such functions exist.
But i cannot generalize it for n vertex tree. Please help.

Suppose $f$ has a minimum $m$ on node $v_i$. Then
$$ m = f(v_i) \geq\frac{\sum\limits_{(v_i, v_j) \in E}f(v_j) } {d(i)} \geq\frac{\sum\limits_{(v_i, v_j) \in E}m } {d(i)} = m.  $$
This implies that for any node $v_j$ connected to $v_i$ the function also takes the same value $m$. Since the graph is connected, you can repeat the same reasoning and show that the function $f$ must be constant.
Notice that I only used that the graph is connected, not that it is a tree. Moreover, the same holds for any strongly connected directed graph with the same proof.

There is also a proof using Perron-Frobenius Theorem (or the Theory of Markov Chains)

You have proved $ f(v_i) \geq m $ this does not implies $ f(v_j) =m$

nono, I proved $f(v_j)=m$
